# Error encountered when try to install keras using pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip, anaconda

I can't install any python module or library using pip on command prompt, whenever I tried to install any module the error occurs. I have the latest version of conda in my system.

The error is as-

> Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\UDIT DEO\Anaconda3\python.exe
>   "C:\Users\UDIT DEO\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py" install keras

Comment: upgrade pip and you are done

Comment: My pip is up to date